# Restarting computer several times makes windows unbootable

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, usb

My bro took my hdmi cable. Seeing that nothing shows up on the screen I restarted computer several time

I got this problem

```
A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.

If this is the first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:

Check to be sure you have adequate disk space. If a driver is identified in the Stop message, disable the driver or check with the manufacturer for driver updates. Try changing video adapters.

Check with your hardware vendor for any BIOS updates. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing. If you need to use Safe Mode to remove or disable components, restart your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup options, and then select Safe Mode.

Technical information:

*** STOP: 0x00000024 (0x0000000000000190494, ...,...,...)
```

After that I tried to repair windows to no avail

THe disk is protected by bitlocker

It seems that the key to unlock the drive is in the USB. Every time I boot my computer I have to insert a USB stick. That USB will automatically contain recovery key for C: drive right?

Then I did chkdsk

Turns out every files have problems

I got Replacing invalid security id with default security id for file 984457

I wonder what happens?

The hard disk is quite shaky

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228888 NTFS error